Does "being in the range" behave well wrt fiber products?
Let $X,Y,Z,W$ be schemes, and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism. Let $p \in Y \times_Z W$ be such that $\pi_1(p) \in range(f)$. Then, does this imply $p \in range(f \times id_W) : X \times_Z W \rightarrow Y \times_Z W$?
My attempt is as follows:
Let $y = f(x) = \pi_1(p)$. Let $w = \pi_2(p)$. Let $z\in Z$ be the point $p$ is sent to. Then, $p$ is a prime ideal in $k(y) \otimes_{k(z)} k(w)$ (stacks project 26.17.5). Since $f(x) = y$, there is a ring homomorphism $k(y) \rightarrow k(x)$, which induces  $k(y) \otimes_{k(z)} k(w) \rightarrow k(x) \otimes_{k(z)} k(w)$.
This is where I got stuck. I don't know what to do with the prime ideal $p$. If there is a prime ideal $q$ of $k(x) \otimes_{k(z)} k(w)$ that pulls back to $p$, then I think $q$ is a preimage of $p$. But I don't know how to prove that $q$ exists.

There's a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X \times_{Z} W @>{f \times \operatorname{id}_{W}}>> Y \times_{Z} W @>{\pi_{2}}>> W\\
@V{g}VV @VV\pi_{1}V @VVV\\
X @>>{f}> Y @>>> Z
\end{CD}
where both squares are cartesian. We have $x \in X$ and $p \in Y \times_{Z} W$ such that $f(x) = \pi_{1}(p)$, so (by the Stacks Project Lemma you cited, for example) there exists some $q \in X \times_{Z} W$ such that $g(q) = x$ and $(f \times \operatorname{id}_{W})(q) = p$.
